# Getting files open in all gvims

Tags: ubuntu, gvim, process

On ubuntu, is it possible to get the full path to all files currently open in `gvim`? The results from `ps` are only a relative path from where `gvim` was started. My end goal is to generate a shell script of gvim commands which will reopen all of my currently open source files the next time I sit down to work.

Comment: Why not to use http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010 ? Personally I have lots of reasons (e.g. my sessions should exclude all non-projects files opened for reviewing ), but whats yours?

Comment: @mhambra: I'm finding myself navigating all over the place to get at source files needed for a particular task. I thought it would be nice to take a snapshot of my gvims to make it quickly get back to this state later. Will that script actually accomplish that? Looks to me like it's more for saving a vim environment...

Answer (score 1):

Get PIDs of vim processes:

```
[srv]~|> ps -C vim -o pid=
4733
4828
```

Get files opened by PID:

```
[srv]~|> ls -l /proc/4733/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user grp 64 2011-05-31 14:48 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user grp 64 2011-05-31 14:48 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user grp 64 2011-05-31 14:47 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user grp 64 2011-05-31 14:48 3 -> socket:[54963]
lrwx------ 1 user grp 64 2011-05-31 14:48 5 -> /home/user/.wmark.ps.swp
```

File opened here: ~/wmark.ps

Comment: How do I know which of the results from ls is the swap file for the file I'm editing? Also, vim doesn't always create a swap file, so this might be somewhat unreliable.